# RandomForest High OOB Score Vs Low KFold validation score

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, ensemble-learning

I've been training random forest model with titanic dataset.
Many articles point that we dont need cross validation for RF classifiers while few say you can use cross validation. I tried both and I dont know what to make of the scores and I suspect my model is overfitting if used without cross validation.

The model's oob score is 96.85 and mean cross validation score is 83.27 [ This models gives 74.01 if I set scoring='f1' ]

Here is my code,

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=44, oob_score=True)

clf.fit(titanic[features], titanic['Survived'])

clf.score(titanic[features], titanic['Survived'])

score : 0.9685746352413019
```

```
predictors = features
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=10, n_estimators=10)
clf.fit(titanic[features],titanic["Survived"])

kf = KFold(n_splits=10)

scores = cross_val_score(clf, titanic[predictors], titanic["Survived"], cv=kf)

print(scores.mean())
score : 83.27
```

Can someone please shed lights on this scores?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`clf.score` does not return the OOB score but the one on training data.

OOB score is accessed via the `clf.oob_score_` method.